# git push fatal: unable to access 'http://git.anfubaoxian.cn/java/afb_admin.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500

Tags: git, push, gitlab

I got the 500 error, I know it's that incorrect service was found, and the error message clearly shows me why: however, I have already tried restart the git service!but It don't work! please help.

I think I need to reset Git service. Or else ways, please advise!

Answer (score 1):

> and the error message clearly shows me why:

Not exactly: it just indicates something was wrong on the GitLab (since it is a GitLab server) side.
You need to check the [production.log](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/logs.html) on the server side to find the actual root cause.